# saving date to sql database from winform using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I am working on winforms using c# where I have a class User having datetime dob variable whose value is inserted into database (type of database column is date).

the function in user class is :

```
        {
            string format = "yyyy-MM-dd";

            if (mail.IsMatch(id) && password.Length >= 8 && password == confrmpass)
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand($"insert into UserInfo (Username,Password,[Full Name],Email,Address,[Date of birth]) values ('{username}','{password}','{name}','{id}','{address}','{dob.ToString(format)}'", con);                    
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

next this class object is made in Form:

```
User user1 = new User();
  user1.register(textname.Text.ToString(),textemail.Text,textaddress.Text,textuser.Text,textpassword.Text,textconfirmpass.Text,metroDateTime1.Value.Date);
```

where the date is passed by using the datetimepicker.

Now I am having error

```
'Incorrect syntax near '2020-08-31'.'
```

why I am having error when the sql date format is same.
How can I solve this.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is [use parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/). Then you need to learn why [that's not how to store passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120540/).

Comment: Use SQL Parameters.

Answer (score -2):

You forgot to close your values opening ( with ) after DOB, edit below.

```
{
        string format = "yyyy-MM-dd";

        if (mail.IsMatch(id) && password.Length >= 8 && password == confrmpass)
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand($"insert into UserInfo (Username,Password,[Full Name],Email,Address,[Date of birth]) values ('{username}','{password}','{name}','{id}','{address}','{dob.ToString(format)}')", con);                    
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
}
```

Comment: I just want to note that while this fixes the issue as posted, it's not a good solution. Everyone needs to be parameterizing their SQL.

Comment: Thank you so much, I made such a silly mistake and was wondering what's wrong from hours. Thanks a lot

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @Maria please please do not use code like this; it allows anyone to totally take over your database, it leaks passwords, it breaks on different date localisations. There are too many problems with this code; please read the links we have posted.

Comment: Something like the approach of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection should be followed.

Comment: @borrelito - You can use `SqlCommand` and parameterize. They aren't mutually exclusive by any means. In fact, that's exactly how it's done in the linked duplicate.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb i wrote something my head wanted then it turned out to somethinng different :D I edited my comment

Comment: Ok thank you all, I am actually learning and its my very first time using database and winforms so I don't have much knowledge but surely I am use this information from now on. Thanks a lot